# Conditional Registration of Decorator based on Generic Parameter using SimpleInjector

Tags: c#, .net, simple-injector

I have a query handler like this:

```
public class FooQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<FooQuery, FooResult>
{
      public FooResult Handle(FooQuery query) {
          // Query handled here.
      }
}
```

The `IQueryHandler` interface is defined as:

```
public interface IQueryHandler<TQuery, Result> : where TQuery : IQuery
{
    TResult Handle(TQuery query);
}
```

`FooQuery` is defined as:

```
public class FooQuery : IAuthorizedQuery
```

where `IAuthorizedQuery` is defined as:

```
public interface IAuthorizedQuery : IQuery
```

`IQuery` is just simple interface. `FooResult` is just a simple DTO object.

The `IQueryHandler` is injected using Simple Injector and is registered with the container as:

```
container.Register(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), assemblies);
```

***The Problem***

I want to decorate the `IQueryHandler` with a decorator handler class. This decorator should be applied conditionally only if the query object (e.g. `FooQuery`) implements `IAuthorizedQuery`.  This is so some role-based authorization can occur.

If the query does not implement `IAuthorizedQuery` and only `IQuery` then no decoration should take place.

The handler will need to look like:

```
 public AuthorizationQueryDecorator : IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> 
    where TQuery : IAuthorizedQuery 
 {
      public AuthorizationQueryDecorator(
            IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> handler,
            IAuthorizer<TQuery> authorizer)    
      {
           _authorizer = authorizer;
           _handler = handler;
      }

      private readonly IAuthorizer<TQuery> _authorizer;
      private readonly IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult> handler;

      public TResult Handle(TQuery query) {
          if(!_authorizer.Authorise(query)) {
              // throw exception
          }
          else {
               handler.Handle(query);
          }
      }
 }
```

The `IAuthorizer<TQuery>` interface is just a simple interface with a boolean method `Authorise(TQuery query)` that returns true if the query can be executed based on some role-based logic.

The problem is I'm not sure how to register the decorator conditionally with SimpleInjector.

The condition is essentially that an `IQueryHandler` should only be decorated if the TQuery object implements IAuthorizationQuery.

How can I do this?

At the moment I have

```
 container.RegisterDecorator(
            typeof(IQueryHandler<,>),
            typeof(AuthorizationQueryDecorator<,>), \\\ PREDICATE?);
```

but I don't know what Predicate should be specified?

***EDIT***

It looks as though the issue I'm having is with the `IAuthorizer` registration.

I have the following `IAuthorizer` implementations:

```
public FooQueryAuthorizer() : IAuthorizer<FooQuery>
```

and

```
public NullQueryAuthorizer<TQuery, TResult> : IQueryAuthorizer<TQuery, TResult>
    where TQuery : IAuthorizedQuery<TResult> : IAuthorizer
```

The SimpleInjector registration for `IQueryAuthorizer` is:

```
            container.RegisterConditional(
            typeof(IQueryAuthorizer<,>),
            typeof(NullQueryAuthorizer<,>),
            c => !c.Handled);
```

However, the `NullQueryAuthorizer` is always used, regardless of whether a specific implementation (e.g. `FooQueryAuthorizer`) is present.

How can I get round this?

Comment: If you make `IQuery` a generic type containing the return type (i.e. `IQuery<TResult>`) this gives you a lot of extra metadata to query on, and it gives you compile time support and prevents you from having to cast (and find out at runtime that you are using the wrong query). [This article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92) describes this model using the generic `IQuery<TResult>`.

Comment: Thanks Steven - in practice it is, I'd just stripped out the <TResult> parameter on the question to make it a bit clearer

Comment: How is the `FooQueryAuthorizer` registered?

Comment: I bet the (new) problem you are having is caused by the registration of different types. `IQueryAuthorizer<T, R>` might derive from `IAuthorizer<T>` but the conditional registration registers a `IQueryAuthorizer<T, R>`  instead of a `IAuthorizer<T>`; for Simple Injector these are completely different types; it won't automatically resolved types based on a base type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything; Simple Injector will automatically apply generic type constraints for you. So your registration is simply this:

```
container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(IQueryHandler<,>),
    typeof(AuthorizationQueryDecorator<,>));
```

The documentation [describes](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#registration-of-open-generic-types):

> Simple Injector will automatically apply the registered type conditionally based on it generic type constraints

Comment: Thanks Steven - since posting, I think the issue I'm having is actually related to the `IQueryAuthorizer` registration.  I've updated the question.